# Calculating No of Days after 24 Hours rather than midnight in Excel

Tags: excel, time, average, formula, days

How to calculate exact number of Days and time between complaint opening and closing?

Right now i am using this formula:

```
=INT(D4-B4)&" Days "&HOUR(MOD(C4-A4,1))&" Hour "&MINUTE(MOD(C4-A4,1))&" Minutes"
```

But it is not calculating the exact number of days as you see below it is showing one day but actually it is only 22 hours. I want that it start adding one day after completing 24 hours not after midnight.

```
Complaint Opening   Complaint Closing   Closing Duration
Time    Date        Time    Date
9:00 AM 21-03-17    7:00 AM 22-03-17    1 Days 22 Hour 0 Minutes
```

Comment: Try this: `=TEXT(C4+D4-A4-B4, "d"" Days ""H"" Hours ""m"" Minutes""")`

Comment: That's OK up to 31 days but "d" format doesn't count higher (because it's day of month), so to cater for days > 31 best to use =INT(C4+D4-A4-B4) for days and TEXT function for hours and minutes